# Computing e^(-j) in C

Tags: c, complex-numbers, exponential

I need to compute imaginary exponential in C.

As far as I know, there is no complex number library in C. It is possible to get `e^x` with `exp(x)` of `math.h`, but how can I compute the value of `e^(-i)`, where `i = sqrt(-1)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that exponent of complex number equals:

```
e^(ix) = cos(x)+i*sin(x)
```

Then:

```
e^(-i) = cos(-1)+i*sin(-1)
```

Answer (score 18):

In C99, there is a `complex` type. Include `complex.h`; you may need to link with `-lm` on gcc. Note that Microsoft Visual C does not support `complex`; if you need to use this compiler, maybe you can sprinkle in some C++ and use the [`complex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0352zzhd.aspx) template.

`I` is defined as the imaginary unit, and `cexp` does exponentiation. Full code example:

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    complex x = cexp(-I);
    printf("%lf + %lfi\n", creal(x), cimag(x));
    return 0;
}
```

See [`man 7 complex`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/complex) for more information.

Comment: I needed to do this manually.. Thanks for the future reference, I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 6):

Using the **Euler's Formula** you have that `e^-i == cos(1) - i*sin(1)`

Comment: e^(-k) = cos(k) - i*sin(k), you mean.

Comment: yes, but in his case k = 1. In any case the general form is e^(-ki) = cos(k)-i*sin(k), not e^(-k)

Answer (score 2):

`e^-j` is just `cos(1) - j*sin(1)`, so you can just generate the real and imaginary parts using real functions.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the cartesian form

if `z = m*e^j*(arg);`

```
re(z) = m * cos(arg);
im(z) = m * sin(arg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is calling a c++ function a solution for you? The C++ STL has a nice complex-class and boost also has to offer some nice options. Write a function in C++ and declare it "extern C"

```
extern "C" void myexp(float*, float*);

#include <complex>

using std::complex;

void myexp (float *real, float *img )
{
  complex<float> param(*real, *img);
  complex<float> result = exp (param);
  *real = result.real();
  *img = result.imag();
}
```

Then you can call the function from whatever C-code you rely on ( Ansi-C, C99, ...).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myexp(float*, float*);

int main(){
    float real = 0.0;
    float img = -1.0;
    myexp(&real, &img);
    printf ("e^-i = %f + i* %f\n", real, img);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but C++ is no good for me with this

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it can be done directly:

```
std::exp(std::complex<double>(0, -1));
```

Comment: this question is tagged with C, not C++